# CSRF TOKEN per session

Tags: java, csrf, csrf-token

How can I generate a single csrf token per session and it does not change by request with google as the login in java?

I enable csrf token

```
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

I made a controller so that the front receives the token

```
 @GetMapping("/csrf")
 public CsrfToken csrf(CsrfToken token) {
     return token;
 }
```